# How to return "Not built" to Gerrit Trigger Plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit-trigger

There are 4 kind gerrit command in gerrit plugin settings.
Success / Fail / Unstable / Not Built.

I could return "success/fail" from my job to gerrit plugin, by using exit 0/1,
And "success/fail" gerrit command was executed.
But I don't Understand how to return "Not Built" by shellscript.
Please teach me.

sorry for my poor english.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Success / Failure / Unstable**

1. If the job has no test reports configured:

   - If the last build command executed by Jenkins exits with failure
     (<> 0) exit code, the build is considered to be **failed**.
   - If the last build command exits with success (= 0) exit
     code, the build is **successful**.
2. If the job has one or more test reports configured:

   - If the last build command executed by Jenkins exits with failure
     (<> 0) exit code, the build is considered to be **failed**.
   - If the last build command exits with success (= 0) exit
     code but test reports have some failed tests, the build is **unstable**.
   - If the last build command exits with success and all test have
     passed, the build is **stable**.

The only other way to get "Unstable" result is through the use of some post-build plugins (like static code analysis for example).

**Not Built**

I'm not sure about this item... but I think (guess) the build is considered not build when the job finishes by a timeout.

Comment: thx for detail answer.I understand "Not Built" cannot be set explicitly by user.

Answer (score 0):

I found out way of force stopping by following command

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/job/${JOB_NAME}/${BUILD_NUMBER}/stop
```

and gerrit command for "Not Build" was executed .